# eledmac package: \pausenumbering and \resumenumbering

Tags: line-numbering, eledmac

I'm using the `eledmac` package to typeset a rather large work of theology. For simplicity and the sake of a MWE, I'm just using the two stanza poem below.

**Intended outcome**: Between sections that are line numbered, I would like to interpose text that is not line numbered. Typically, one would do this using the `\beginnumbering` and `\endnumbering` commands. However, these commands reset the line numbers back to 0 (or 1?). I would like the line number to resume after the interposed, non-line-numbered text.

According to the `eledmac` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eledmac/eledmac.pdf), page 11, I should be able to use the commands `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` to accomplish this.

**Problem statements**:

1. The manual seems to contradict itself (again, see page 11). It says, "Use `\pausenumbering` only between numbered paragraphs." It also says, "We have defined these commands ... in case you find it necessary to insert text between numbered sections without disturbing the line numbering."
2. In either use case, i.e., whether using `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` between numbered paragraphs *or* with interposed text, I get error messages.
3. The variations on errors follow:

   - If compiled as submitted in the MWE below (using `PDFLaTeX` in all cases), line numbering stops at line 10, does not resume with "Little Lamb, I'll tell thee ...", and I receive the error `line 45: Extra \endgroup \endgroup`.
   - If I comment out the "offending" `\endgroup` on line 45, the error message goes away, but line number still does not resume.
   - Trying to use process of elimination, if I comment out the interposing text and the `\endgroup` command, I get no errors, but line number still does not resume.

A few final points:

- I have  changed the `memoir` document class to both `article` and `book`, but no joy.
- Yes, I know that `eledmac` is a 3-pass system.
- I've tried replacing the use of `\autopar` with the `\pstart` and `\pend` pair, still no joy. Beside, the actual work will be several hundred pages and I definitely don't want to have to mark every paragraph!
- I have tried to search this site for something relevant and haven't been able to do so.

  ```
  \documentclass{memoir}

  \usepackage{eledmac} % Version 1.10.3, dated 2014-04-07

  \begin{document}

  \textbf{The Lamb}

  \emph{William Blake}

  \begingroup
  \beginnumbering
  \autopar
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}

  Little Lamb, who made thee\\
  Dost thou know who made thee,\\
  Gave thee life, and bid thee feed\\
  By the stream and o'er the mead;\\
  Gave thee clothing of delight,\\
  Softest clothing, woolly, bright;\\
  Gave thee such a tender voice,\\
  Making all the vales rejoice?\\
  Little Lamb, who made thee?\\
  Dost thou know who made thee?

  \pausenumbering

  This is a line between the two stanzas that should \emph{not} be number, because it is prefaced with the \verb|\pausenumbering| command.

  \resumenumbering

  Little Lamb, I'll tell thee;\\
  Little Lamb, I'll tell thee:\\
  He is called by thy name,\\
  For He calls Himself a Lamb\\
  He is meek, and He is mild,\\
  He became a little child.\\
  I a child, and thou a lamb,\\
  We are call\'ed by His name.\\
  Little Lamb, God bless thee!\\
  Little Lamb, God bless thee!

  \endnumbering
  \endgroup

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: By the way, karkoeller, thank you for fixing the code in my question!

Comment: that is a bug in eledmac. I am working on.  see https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/163. I will ask you for test when I will think to have a solution

Answer (score 4):

Effectively, it seems to be a bug in `eledmac`.

Anyway, to pause and resume numbering you can encase your stanzas inside `\pstart`...`\pend` (without `\autopar`) in this way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{eledmac} % Version 1.10.3, dated 2014-04-07

\begin{document}

\textbf{The Lamb}

\emph{William Blake}

\begingroup
\beginnumbering
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\pstart
Little Lamb, who made thee\\
Dost thou know who made thee,\\
Gave thee life, and bid thee feed\\
By the stream and o'er the mead;\\
Gave thee clothing of delight,\\
Softest clothing, woolly, bright;\\
Gave thee such a tender voice,\\
Making all the vales rejoice?\\
Little Lamb, who made thee?\\
Dost thou know who made thee?
\pend

This is a line between the two stanzas that should \emph{not} be number, because it is prefaced with the \verb|\pausenumbering| command.

\pstart
Little Lamb, I'll tell thee;\\
Little Lamb, I'll tell thee:\\
He is called by thy name,\\
For He calls Himself a Lamb\\
He is meek, and He is mild,\\
He became a little child.\\
I a child, and thou a lamb,\\
We are call\'ed by His name.\\
Little Lamb, God bless thee!\\
Little Lamb, God bless thee!
\pend

\endnumbering
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I copied and pasted your code directly and it does work, so I was doing something wrong when I initially tried this. So, +1 for you!  :-)  HOWEVER, as noted above, the actual document is going to be several hundred pages and marking every paragraph accordingly would be (shall we say) less than an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug in eledmac. Could you please try the fix?

1. Dowload https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/issue163.zip
2. Run the .ins file
3. Put the .sty file along you .tex file
4. Try.

Comment: Let me be sure I have properly followed your orders. 1) Run `latex` on `eledmac.ins` (done). 2) Put `eledmac.sty` in the same directory as my test file (done). 3) Run `latex` on my test file 3 times (done).

Still no joy. And I'm still getting the `Extra \endgroup. l.45 \endgroup` error.

Oh yes, one other thing I tried. After a couple of tries, I also put the new `.sty` file where the old one is, just in case it was some sort of path issue.

Comment: sorry, I forget to send the modification on the servor. Try again now.

Comment: Well, you fixed the `Extra \endgroup` issue!  :-)  It may be helpful for you to know that the `foo.2` file remains a zero byte file; whereas the `foo.1` file has 10 lines of `\@l[1][1]`, as I guess it should (there being 10 lines in the 1st stanza).

Comment: ok. I will publish the release in next days

Comment: I have uploaded the release in the CTAN.

Comment: I appreciate the quick turn-around! However (sorry), the outcome remains the same. Compiling my `foo.tex` file in TeXStudio, I get the same results. Compiling from the command line does get different results, in that `foo.1` remains 0 bytes, `foo.2` never gets written. The net outcome is still the same. Would you like to see the log files? I wish I could be more helpful!

Comment: Is it possible that your fixes have broken the `\edindex` functionality? `\edindex` does not write to the `.IDX` file using the `\makeidx` package. No entries, therefore, no index.

Comment: what version did you tried? on the ctan, the upload is not yet available.

Comment: for the problem of indexing, please open a issue on github. That is not the same

Comment: I'm sorry - I was trying the last version you sent to me. I should have waited.

Comment: which version? I have only send to you a link to a version which you said it was ok.

Comment: Please see my comments above from yesterday beginning "I appreciate the quick turn-around!" I said that "the ... outcome is still the same," by which I meant that `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` still do not work correctly. The only thing that seemed to have been solved was the `Extra \endgroup` error message. That's why I wondered if seeing my log file would be helpful.

Comment: please open a issue on github, it will be better for the exchange. I don't see with your MWE where is the problem. My output is correct. From Little to thee -> line 1 to 10. From this to command -> not numbered. From Little to Thee ->l. 11 to 20

Comment: please contact me via github. I don't understand your remaining problem.

Comment: Sorry - not ignoring you. It's Easter week and I'm a pastor, so it's kind of hectic here. I'll try to work on this tomorrow afternoon (note that it's 1 am here as I write this!).

Comment: ok, i will be on holiday, so it will be corrected next week

Comment: I have uploaded my MWE to GitHub, as requested.

Comment: thanks, I think I have understand your problem and solve it. Please answer in github

Comment: You have solved it. Thank you for your patience and persistence.

Comment: you're welcome. the problem was easy. the only need was to understand it.